# Allow multiple values with SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to use IN @Parameter while using dateadd function in below code

```
 declare @interval int
--set @interval
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS Row, 
       RIGHT(LEFT(E.Name,  11), 8) AS Device, P.[DateTime],
       day(p.DateTime) AS Day,
       month(p.DateTime) AS Month,  
       P.AverageValue, p.StandardDeviation
FROM [dbo].[vManagedEntity] AS E  
INNER JOIN [Perf].[vPerfDaily] AS P ON E.ManagedEntityRowId = P.ManagedEntityRowId    
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vPerformanceRuleInstance] AS I ON 
P.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId = I.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vPerformanceRule] AS R ON R.RuleRowId = I.RuleRowId
WHERE     right(left(e.name,6),3)  IN (@Site) 
      AND R.CounterName = 'MPLS    Utilization % (Average)' 
      AND p.DateTime >= DATEADD(MM, (@interval), GetUTCDate())
```

I want to use like

```
p.DateTime >= DATEADD(MM, IN (@interval), GetUTCDate())
```

but it is not allowing it.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: An error occured during local Report processsing. An error occured during Report processing. Query execution failed for dataset 'dataset1. 'Incorrect Syntax near ','.

Comment: I mean the sql error. There should be something like that. Where do you actually set `@interval`? Is there a value set for it?

Comment: Yes i am taking value like last 3 months , last 6 months , last 1 year ..

Comment: Why do you actually want to use `IN`? `@interval` is an `int`. That does not make sense to me

Comment: actually data is from SCOM DW and i want to use it to generate the forecast Report and generate trendline

Comment: i want to take  intervals like check values from last 3 months and Show graph and same for last 6 months values.

Comment: what i want is to get the values from last 3 months and Show the graph then get values from last 6 months and Show in same graph

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!